# How to reference/choose a column in the current dataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to reference a column in a dataFrame by its name, In the spark shell I could use **$**, which is unknown when compiling code.
here is an example :

```
val df:DataFrame= Seq(
   ("Alex", "04/01/1992"),
   ("Sarah","01/01/2000"),
   ("David","01/01/2005")
  ).toDf("name","Birthdate").to_date($"Birthday")
```

in this example I'm creating a dataFrame, and trying to convert the type of birthday from string to date, however, when coding the **$** is not accepted so I have to create an intermediate value :

```
    val df1:DataFrame= Seq(
           ("Alex", "04/01/1992"),
           ("Sarah","01/01/2000"),
           ("David","01/01/2005")
          ).toDf("name","Birthdate")
   val df2= df1.to_date($"Birthday")
```

Is there a way to get ride of the intermediate variable ?
what is the equivalent of $ in scala code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can access columns using **`col("<col_name>") (or) '<col_name> (or) $"<col_name>" (or) col_name`** in scala.

**`Example:`**

```
val df:DataFrame= Seq(("Alex", "04/01/1992"),("Sarah","01/01/2000"),("David","01/01/2005")).toDF("name","Birthdate")

//using withColumn supports col("<col_name>") (or) '<col_name> (or) $"<col_name>"
df.withColumn("Birthdate",to_date(col("Birthdate"),"dd/MM/yyyy")).show()
df.withColumn("Birthdate",to_date('Birthdate,"dd/MM/yyyy")).show()
df.withColumn("Birthdate",to_date($"Birthdate","dd/MM/yyyy")).show()

//using .select supports col("<col_name>") (or) '<col_name> (or) $"<col_name>"
df.select(to_date('Birthdate,"dd/MM/yyyy")).show()
df.select(to_date($"Birthdate","dd/MM/yyyy")).show()
df.select(to_date(col("Birthdate"),"dd/MM/yyyy")).show()

//using .select(expr) and .selectExpr supports <col_name>
df.select(expr("to_date(Birthdate,'dd/MM/yyyy')Birthdate")).show()
df.selectExpr("to_date(Birthdate,'dd/MM/yyyy')Birthdate").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use col and withColumn:

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col,to_date}

val df= Seq(
   ("Alex", "04/01/1992"),
   ("Sarah","01/01/2000"),
   ("David","01/01/2005")
  ).toDF("name","Birthdate").withColumn("Birthdate", to_date(col("Birthdate"),"dd/MM/yyyy")).show()

+-----+----------+
| name| Birthdate|
+-----+----------+
| Alex|1992-01-04|
|Sarah|2000-01-01|
|David|2005-01-01|
+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Coool that's what I'm looking for,